# Dagster get partition of job ran before sensor triggered

Tags: sensors, execution-time, dagster

I want to get the partition of a job that is than before a sensor is trigger. I not sure how to do that in dagster.

I have a sensor looks like this:

```
@sensor(job=job2)
def run_job2_after_job1:
date= datetime.now()

run = context.intance.get_run_records(filters = runsfilter(job_name = job1)

for run in runs:
        yield RunRequest(
            run_key = run.dagster_run.run_id,
            partition_key = date
        )
```